# Why does Stack Overflow create imgur images when you copy paste from excel?

Tags: support, editor, image-upload

Imgur images can't be easily reproduced and make it harder to answer questions, this shouldn't be a feature by default.

Comment: @yivi I'm on linux, copy paste from libreoffice or excel and stackoverflow will bring up imgur.

Comment: Then why you bring up Excel? There is no Excel on Linux. But still an OS/Application thing.

Comment: I believe the clipboard contains several different representations of the Excel data. Since one of those representations is an image, it uses that representation when pasting to Stack Overflow. If you just want the text, paste it into Notepad (or text editor that only allows text) first, then copy it from there.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381951/copy-paste-from-ms-word-triggers-image-upload and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320162/cant-paste-data-to-question-get-prompted-for-image

Comment: @pyCthon cross-site duplication is not supported though.

Comment: I voted to close it, this is a bug the SO devs probably won't fix.

Comment: It seems you do not understand what either dupe or the answer on this question are telling you. **It is not a bug. It's a feature**. And this time for real.

Comment: @yivi Downvote me all you want it's still a bug

Comment: @pyCthon if it's intended behavior, it's by definition not a bug.

Answer (score 10):

Excel sends various representation of the copied content into the clipboard; the client decides which one it wants to use when pasting - here the client is a textbox in your browser, and it's apparently happy to treat the content as an image:

[image: Simple Excel table pasted as an image]

Copy your Excel source and instead of Ctrl+V to paste as an image, right-click and select *Paste as plain text* (or Ctrl+Shift+V if your browser supports it) - then format as code (select all, Ctrl+K):

```
A   B   C
1   2   3
```

Comment: Nice solution but I have to disable my adblock to get `ctrl+shift+v` to work on firefox... not happening.

Comment: @pyCthon then first paste it somewhere that you can copy it back in plain text format, like Notepad. I'm failing to see the connection between adblock and "paste as plain text" though.